# VBA move data into open workbook from closed workbook with conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to move data from closed sheet to open sheet under some conditions but it doesn't work for me. I've need to check row by row and copy only the rows that meeting with my conditions. can you help me see the problem and fix it? much obliged

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer, i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    directory = "C:\Work\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx??")

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        For i = 0 To 278
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Range("a1:a3").Copy
        Next i

        ' For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
            ' total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            ' Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
            ' after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
        ' Next sheet

        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        fileName = Dir()
     Loop

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the Dir function will only return the first file that matches your query, so you are only pulling one file name.

As for the loop, you aren't using the control variable "i" anywhere in your statements so you are copying the same range (A1:A3) every iteration. You should have something like:

```
For i = 1 to 278
    If Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Rows(i).Cells(i,1).Value > 10 then
         Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Rows(i).Copy
    Endif
next i
```

This will iterate through the first 278 rows of the first worksheet in the workbook and copy only the rows where the value in the first cell is greater than 10.

Comment: hi I've tried it, but it appears it doesn't work. it giving me error when i try to do so